# How can I speed up my PHP includes?

Tags: php, caching

I have once PHP file that I include to pretty much everything I call. This one include file has several other php files that it includes. The reason I use this one file for all my including is because I have path differences between my dev and production server and it is nice to only have to include one file and know that I have the classes that I need right there.

Is there any easy way to cache the file, or something to speed up my load times?

Comment: What kind of load time difference are we talking about? An include, even one that includes other files shouldn't be noticeable. Are you also instantiating classes at the same time? Connecting to a DB?

Have you tried just loading your initial page without the file includes to see the time difference?

Comment: Write a small script which creates your "master include" once and writes the result in a new file which is then used to include by all other pages? That way you do the large number of includes only once. But you have to do it manually.

Comment: When I do a fairly simple AJAX request it can take up to 3 seconds to return when it is just pulling HTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to handle path differences than do not involve loading everything every time. You can, for instance, define a constant and use it as prefix in all your file system operations:

```
define('DOC_ROOT', '/var/www/foo');
require_once DOC_ROOT . '/lib/bar.php';
```

Or you can rely in your system's DOCUMENT_ROOT variable (if set and correct):

```
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/lib/bar.php';
```

Or you can use [class  autoloading](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php). Or you can use [include_path](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path).

Apart from that, PHP will always *find* and *parse* every file with PHP source code you instruct it to, every time you run your script. You can shorten the second part if you install an [opcode cache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_PHP_accelerators).

Comment: I am using the DOCUMENT_ROOT at the moment to get everything to load correctly, though I do have to correct it since on one of the servers it does not have an ending slash and on the other it does. I have added class autoloading, and that seems to have helped significantly. Thank you.

Comment: +1 for class autoloading, though for classes that are *always* included, you should put the `include` statement. For example, if a library class extends another library class, you should have the `require_once` on top of the file (this is what is done in many frameworks).

Answer (score 3):

You can install an opcode cache for PHP

- [APC](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php)
- [xcache](http://xcache.lighttpd.net/)

An opcode cache optimizes performance by removing the compilation time of PHP scripts by caching the compiled state of PHP scripts into RAM and uses the compiled version straight from the RAM. This will increase the rate of page generation time. It also means your files will only be included once.